# Raw SQL with "IF NOT EXISTS" doesn't execute

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlalchemy, pymssql

This is my python code. It seems that if the raw SQL contains `IF NOT EXISTS`, sqlalchemy will not execute it. There is no exception thrown either.

```
db.execute(text(
    """
    IF NOT EXISTS ( select 1 from agent_assignment where exception_id = :exception_id )
    BEGIN
        insert into agent_assignment(exception_id, [user], work_status, insert_date, insert_user)
        values (:exception_id, :user, 'pending', :date, :insert_update_user)
    END
    ELSE
        update agent_assignment
        set 
            [user] = :user,
            update_date = :date,
            update_user = :insert_update_user
        where exception_id =  :exception_id
    """),
    exception_id = exception_id, 
    user = assignee,
    date = datetime.now(),
    insert_update_user = insert_update_user
)
```

If I remove the `IF..ELSE` part, the SQL will execute correctly. So I guess technically it is impossible to execute the raw SQL with `IF..ELSE` or `EXISTS` being a part of the statement?

What is the proper way to run raw SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you need single quotes around the parameter values that get replaced, like `':user'` instead of `:user`? Is this in a try/catch block of some kind? Usually when a query doesn't execute, there's a reason.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Actually the quotes will be added. I have tested this. Thx.

Comment: *shrug* you need to debug your code and ensure that any error that's potentially being swallowed / ignored and/or run a trace in SQL Server to see what actual SQL query is being sent. Have you considered passing parameters to a stored procedure instead of building this ad hoc SQL in your application code?

Answer (score 0):

I need to add `COMMIt` at the end of the script since the query is kinda complex and somehow sqlalchemy can't auto commit it.

Comment: you can also use autocommit on a per-statement basis, e.g. text("my string").execution_options(autocommit=True), see [text()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=text#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) and [execution_options()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Executable.execution_options).